# How to load another project migrations into flyway?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I have a project with many **.sql** migration files. Now I'm moving those files to an external project, so they can be loaded by every of my applications that use flyway. But flyway can't see those files. Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `flyway` with `spring-boot` you can specify flyway files location in your `application.yaml` by:

```
flyway:
  locations: classpath:db/migration/dev
```